# Hiding a UIView

Tags: objective-c, xib

I have several UIViews that are on my xib file and would like to dynamically hide them when I want. I have the following code below but for some reason it's not hiding them. Any ideas what I could do?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //hide all the static UIviews
    _searchBox.hidden = YES;
    _searchButton.hidden = YES;
    _logo.hidden = YES;

    NSLog(@"FIRED THE EVENT");
    //TODO: create a new view that holds a zoomed in image

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are theses items IBOutlet connected to the ones in your nib file? And are the referencing outlets linked? That is usually the cause.

Comment: yes they are. They are linked to the xib through an IBOutlet. Can I not hide these views if they are linked?

Comment: Then they should get hidden. Sry, I meant that when you FORGET to link through the nib, that can be why they don't get hidden but you did remember to do that.